# How can I correctly display an image from my database/table using a php form?

Tags: php

Here are the following scripts I have created. first is the form that allows to select an image to be displayed. Second is the display page. My question is how can I display images from my form using a database/table in php?? I only want to display a single image that I have selected using the select file form.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

 <form action="display.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    Select image to display:
    <input type="file" name="fileToDisplay" id="fileToDisplay">
    <input type="submit" value="Display Image" name="submit">
</form>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the second script

```
<?php

    $db = mysqli_connect("localhost","root", "", "myDB");

    $sql = "SELECT * FROM images";

    $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<img src=' images/". $row['image']."' >";
        echo "<p>". $row['text']."</p>";
        echo "</div>";
    }
```

[image]

Comment: what the issue is having error or something else you can also use javascript or jquery to disply

Comment: where is your image folder?i mean folder structure?why your id seems 0?

Comment: ID should be a PK (primary key) with auto-increment...

Comment: Firstly your table does not seem to contain a column called `text`

Comment: I thing  the space before images breaks your code `' images/....'`, remove it.

Comment: Secondly: I assume from the table design (if that the right word) that these images would be linked somehow to some other table. Is that supposed to be the case?

Comment: Thirdly: `<input type="file"` fields are for allowing the user to select an image from their PC and upload it to the server. _So I am a little confused as to what you are actually trying to achieve here_ As there is no code to actually accept the image and save it somewhere on the server

Comment: Maybe a few minutes with [The manual on PHP File Upload](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php) would help to clarify your thinking

Comment: the code doesn't make sense and user upload an image, then you select an image from db, which image are you selecting?

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way of doing this is to upload the image to the server and save the image name in your database.

**Uploading the image to the server and saving to the database**

```
// display.php
$tmp_file = $_FILES['fileToDisplay']['tmp_name']; // get the temp name of the image
$name = $_FILES['fileToDisplay']['name']; // get the name of the image
```

Now you need to move the file to a directory on your server with [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php) and save the name of the file in the database.

```
move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'images/' . $name)
$remove_extension = explode('.', $name);
$sql = "INSERT INTO `images`(`image`, `text`) VALUES ('$name', '$remove_extension[0]')";
```

**Complete code**

```
// display.php
$tmp_file = $_FILES['fileToDisplay']['tmp_name'];
$name = $_FILES['fileToDisplay']['name'];

if (move_uploaded_file($tmp_file, 'images/' . $name)) {
    $remove_extension = explode('.', $name);
    $sql = "INSERT INTO `images`(`image`, `text`) VALUES ('$name', '$remove_extension[0]')";
   if (mysqli_query($db, $sql)) {
       $last_id = $db->insert_id;
       $sql = "SELECT * FROM images WHERE id = $last_id";

       $result = mysqli_query($db, $sql);
       while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           echo "<div><img src=' images/". $row['image']."' >";
           echo "<p>". $row['text']."</p>";
           echo "</div>";
       }
   }
}
```

[Handling file uploads](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php)